# How can I find all static variables in my c# project?

Tags: c#, static, code-analysis, static-analysis

I want to run some part of my command line programm in parallel with multiple threads and I am afraid that there might be some static variable left that I must fix (e.g. by making it `[ThreadStatic]`). Is there any tool or easy way to find these in my project?

Of course simply searching for `"static"` does not help much: I have lots of static methods that work great and finde with any number of threads

Comment: you could of course use reflection on your assembly. But I dont know, if this would be like letting a bulldozer cleaning your backyard.

Comment: I'm all for the bulldozer approach.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Searching your files for `static:b+:i:b+:i:b*[=;]` with regexp option in Visual Studio should turn up static variables for you. It will also bring operators `==`, but they should be relatively easy to filter out visually.

Comment: Ooo, wait, that's a neat trick.  I think that would work with few false-positives.  +1

Answer (score 18):

**Note:** dasblinkenlight's answer works **only on Visual Studio 2010 and older.**

Below is the translation for Visual Studio 2012 and newer:

`static(?([^\r\n])\s)+(\b(_\w+|[\w-[0-9_]]\w*)\b)(?([^\r\n])\s)+(\b(_\w+|[\w-[0-9_]]\w*)\b)(?([^\r\n])\s)*[=;]`

Translation was made referencing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: By the way, to address the issue that the above will miss any additionally decorated members, use the following impossibly hard to read but effective regex:

`(static(?([^\r\n])\s)+(\b(_\w+|[\w-[0-9_]]\w*)\b)(?([^\r\n])\s)+(\b(_\w+|[\w-[0-9_]]\w*)\b)(?([^\r\n])\s)*[=;])|(static(?([^\r\n])\s)+(\b(_\w+|[\w-[0-9_]]\w*)\b)(?([^\r\n])\s)+(\b(_\w+|[\w-[0-9_]]\w*)\b)(?([^\r\n])\s)+(\b(_\w+|[\w-[0-9_]]\w*)\b)(?([^\r\n])\s)*[=;])`

Comment: ReFiddle for convenience and to not have copy/paste issues: http://refiddle.com/hhg

Comment: This does not work on fields of generic types, such as Dictionary<int, int>.

Comment: These complex regexes miss lots of cases, particularly generic types, as @WaltD says. I find a simple `static.*;` works best for me - very few false positives and negatives in my codebase. False positives are mostly single-line functions and properties but they're really easily spotted.

Comment: These expressions work fine in VS 2019 for Mac, too, but they highlight the challenges with using a single regular expression for this purpose. For example, some projects contain a lot of `static readonly` fields (matched by the longer regex but not the shorter one), which are OK as long as the types are value types. It would be nice to be able to filter those matches out, but it is impractical to do that with a single regex, and the result list in VS provides no further filtering. In the end, under macOS, it was easier to use the shell and a combination of `find` and `grep` commands.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you have to open `Find in Files` windows from `Edit->Find and Replace->Find in Files` menu or Ctrl+Shift+F shortcut keys.

Then you have to use this regular expressions to search all of yours static variables in `Current Project` or in `Entire Solution` :

```
static \w*[ \t]*\b(\w+|[\w-[0-9]]\w)\b[ \t]+\b(\w+|[\w-[0-9]]\w*)\b[ \t]*[=;]
```

Mind check the option `Use Regular Expressions` in `Find options` section.

This regex also supported readonly, virtual, ...

Answer (score 3):

Besides of IDE tricks a real warrior's way would be using `Assembly.Load()` to load application DLL into the memory and then using reflection search through all the types for public/private/protected static fields. 
:)

Comment: And then checking the custom attributes to see if `ThreadStaticAttribute` is missing.  If so, red flags.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to find all of your static fields in one place is likely going to be via the Class View panel in Visual Studio (`Ctrl + W, C` by default in C# mode--also under thew `View` menu).

You can set some primitive filters.  Unfortunately, static is not one of them.  However, you might be able to use the available filters to slim down the results, based on your coding style.

Alternatively, you could make a program that uses reflection to pull out each static field and check its attributes.  If `ThreadStaticAttribute` is not among them, have it spit out a message.  (This is along the lines of another answer, from which you might be able to obtain more details.)